# Multiple Stuck "Downloading Application" Attention required tap here

Tags: 8.0, store

I just got a replacement WP8 Nokia 928 for a defective one.  After putting the SIM card in the new phone from the old I went through the start up options and one of them was to restore from my old phone, it showed the name of the old phone ore start with a clean slate.  I select restore settings from the old phone and everything seemed to be going well until I got an error message that said it was not able to restore because it lost signal (my paraphrase).  Ever since then I have 16 of these messages in my Market place message area, Downloading Application Attention required tap here.  Can I get rid of these w/o resetting my phone?

Comment: Update: I did a reset of my phone and restore from the previous, i.e. the same one I started the other day.  I received no error messages and it finished successfully, but still I have 16 stuck "Downloading Application" Attention required... messages.  Is this a bug?

Comment: If you click those apps they provide more info? I had a similar problem. It was because some apps were removed from the store (but the backup hold them) and apps that were carrier or OEM specifics. I changed from an HTC to a Nokia.

Answer (score 3):

After some frustration and searching I found the answer [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpapps/error-code-8000ffff-on-app-downloads-after-restore/c0025b07-2aa1-45bc-afc2-7f5d98885177).

In short, if you hold the "Downloading application" progress message instead of tapping it, a pop-up dialog appears offering a "Retry" or "Cancel download" option. Tapping "Cancel" successfully cancels the corresponding download.